# Objective-C: Assigning an Array Value as the key for a NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, loops, dictionary

I have a Property list = DictionaryofAddresses, inside which is an NSDictionary StoredAddr;
The keys inside StoredAddr are Mac Addresses, and the values an array of RSI readings.

I have an array, compareAddr (which holds an array of Mac addresses)
I want to use a loop, in which the value at compareaddr[i] will be used as a key, to match whether addresses in my array match any keys in my dictionary.

```
NSArray *compareAddr = [DiscoveredAP allKeys];

for (int i = 0; i < [compareAddr count]; i++){

NSArray *RSIatAddr = [[dictionaryOfAddresses     objectForKey:@"StoredAddr"]objectForKey:compareAddr[i]];
```

The following code gives me an error : 
    expected identifier

Thank you for any help

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Also, variable names should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: `NSArray *RSIatAddr` - Xcode thinks `RSIatAddr` is a Class, not an object. Use lowercase letter as first letter. This should be: `rsiAtAddr`.

Comment: @TomaszSzulc Xcode doesn't assume anything. He can use Uppercase without any problem (yes it's still bad practice, but it is not technically wrong)

Comment: `compareAddr` is array of arrays if it's array of single adresses? It's not clear for me. i think you should declare your `RSIatAddr` above `for loop` and push data to this by `[RSIatAddr addObject:someObject]`.

Comment: I know its bad practice, but RSI reps the RSI, i wanted that to be perfectly clear, sorry for the confusion i'm trying to get the values  which match between my dictionary and my array; Thanks for the inputs though !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[compareAddr objectAtIndex:i]` instead of `compareAddr[i]`

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. Seems like the correct answer to me. EDIT: unless he's using the new obj-c subscript stuff. I forget when that is supposed to be available on iOS.

Comment: For someone who downvotes, please note, author does not use a new form `dictionaryOfAddresses[@"StoredAddr"]`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know who down voted, Thank you for solving the problem though it works now :)